# oracle 10g and define instruction

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I want to compile this PL/SQL program in the SQL window that belongs to the Database Home page:

```
DEFINE p_annual_sal=60000
DECLARE
     v_sal NUMBER(9,2):=&p_annual_sal;
BEGIN
     v_sal:=v_sal/12;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The monthly salary is '|| TO_CHAR(v_sal));
END;
```

When I hit run I got the following message:

> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Even though it works under SQL*Plus of the command line, what it could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in SQL*Plus because `DEFINE` is a SQL*Plus command.

When you refer to the "database home page" I believe you're referring to Oracle Apex's SQL Commands window, which can run SQL and PL/SQL code, but not SQL*Plus commands.

You can do this instead - Apex will prompt you for the input bind variables, if any:

```
DECLARE
     v_sal NUMBER(9,2):= :p_annual_sal;
BEGIN
     v_sal:=v_sal/12;
     dbms_output.put_line('The monthly salary is '|| TO_CHAR(v_sal));
END;
```